# Python/gspread - update multiple cells with different values?

Tags: python, gspread

I am trying to make a price competitor tool with the help of Python/gspread. In google sheets I have column  B3:B5 with multiple competitors links which should be linked to D3:D5 with the multiple competitors prices. Everything works except for the fact that I only get the prices from the first cell of D3 copied into D4, D5 etc.

It should be the link of B3 and the price of D3, B4 - D4 etc

This is the code I use:

## Select range

cell_list = sht1.worksheet("Sheet1").range('D3:D5')

for cell in cell_list:
    cell.value = price

## Update in batch

sht1.worksheet("Sheet1").update_cells(cell_list)

thank you in advance

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `It should be the link of B3 and the price of D3, B4 - D4 etc` and your goal. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike excuse me for the delay, maybe it's easier if I share an article with you (https://towardsdatascience.com/get-rid-of-boring-stuff-using-python-part-2-b84d1e9ea595). At the end you will notice that it's only usuable for 1 item. However I would like to use it for more items. I tried something like you see in my first post and something like: 
'cell_list = sht1.worksheet("Sheet1").range('D3:D5')
for i, cell in enumerate(cell_list):
    cell.value = price[i]

sht1.worksheet("Sheet1").update_cells(cell_list)' 
But both solutions didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information. By the way, if you provide the script related to your question, please add it to your question. Because it is difficult to read the script in the comment.